# How to ssh into Digital Ocean's App Platform app?

Tags: digital-ocean, digital-ocean-apps

We're using digital ocean's cli tool [doctl](https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl#examples), and would like to ssh into our instances using the same cli tool. We're able to list apps using:

```
doctl apps list
```

but cant ssh into apps. Is it even supported by the CLI as of now?

Comment: Is [this](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/doctl/reference/compute/ssh/) what you're looking for? `doctl compute ssh <droplet-id|name>`

Comment: @moonkotte kinda yeah, but when doing `doctl droplets list` i get nothing. so cant run the command above.

Comment: You should run instead `doctl compute droplet list` - [reference](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/doctl/reference/compute/droplet/list/) - since droplets (VMs) are a part of infrastructure or `compute` group

Comment: done that as well, no success. The output doesnt list any of the droplets.

Comment: A _Droplet_ is like a container. An _App_ is more like a managed container. So `doctl` will not work there. TBH I have no idea and am searching for the answer myself.

Comment: I imagine it is unfortunately by design? There's probably additional proprietary infrastructure they include on your container to let them provide the extra managed services you get out of the App Platform. Tradeoffs...

Comment: https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/doctl/reference/apps/ are the limited things we can do with Apps

Comment: Unfortunately seems like Apps dont have SSH enabled...

Answer (score 3):

`doctl apps` does not support the `ssh` sub-command supported by Droplets under `compute`.

REF:

- https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/doctl/reference/apps/
- https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/doctl/reference/compute/ssh/

It does not seem possible to SSH to an DigitalOcean app at this point.

`doctl version 1.98.1-release`

Comment: it is possible to access the instances through the web UI ('console' tab)